# python fdb, trying to connect to an external firebird 1.5 super server

Tags: python, windows-server-2008, firebird

I'm trying to connect to a Firebird 1.5 database that is located on a server, from my local machine with Python  fdb libary.
but I'm having no luck.
the server is windows 2008 server R1 running Firebird 1.5.6 as a service.  It also has a System DSN called `firebird`.
How can i connect to it via python? I'm using this code:

```
import fdb
db = fdb.connect(host='192.168.40.28', database="C:\databases\database12.GDB", user='admin', password='admin')
```

but it generates this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 4, in <module>
    db = fdb.connect(host='192.168.40.28', database="C:\databases\database12.GDB", user='admin', password='admin')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 666, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.40.28".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The system DSN is irrelevant as you aren't using ODBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the IP `192.168.40.28` is correct my next quess would be that you don't have the port `3050` open (thats the default port for Firebird). Check your server's firewall and open the port. You can use some other port instead of `3050` by seting the `RemoteServicePort` parameter in the `firebird.conf` file, but then you have to set the port parameter in the `connect` method too.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated, check that port 3050 is open.

However, **fdb** only supports Firebird 2.0 or higher. For Firebird 1.5, you can use either [pyodbc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/) or [pyfirebirdsql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/firebirdsql/)

<strike>Note that, among other issues (like not handling Firebird INTEGER datatypes properly), pyfirebirdsql isn't 100% compliant with [PEP 249 -- Python DB API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) as calls to `Cursor.rowcount` [always return -1](https://github.com/nakagami/pyfirebirdsql/blob/master/firebirdsql/fbcore.py#L630).</strike>

---

*Edit: After posting this, I took it upon myself to write the code for pyfirebirdsql's `rowcount` function, so now it works as expected, instead of always returning 1. Shortly after that, the pyfirebirdsql author fixed the INTEGER issues as well.*

Answer (score 0):

You must to check the port open in your host as  ain said.
BTW, fdb is just for firebird 2.0 and higher.
Check it out.
 https://fdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#installation

Comment: then what other libary can i use?